# Which datatype for base64 encoded image?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Question: In order to store logos in a database and display them dynamically in ms-reporting service, I need to base64 encode the image. It doesn't work with binary saved images, due to MS limitations...

Now my question: Which datatype do I use? Varchar, nvarchar or text?

I guess varchar would be good enough, since base64 encoded, but images might be larger than 4000 characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varchar(max) supports up to 2GB, and since the data is already base64 encoded, unicode storage won't be required.

http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Importance-of-choosing-the-right-LOB-storage-technique.aspx