# Which column datatype to use with MS Access to save a Base64 image

Tags: database, database-design, base64, ms-access-2010

I have a MS Access 2010 database, in which I would like to save an image Base64 encoded.
What datatype  should I use?

This Image will be Uploaded, Encoded and Saved by a Web Interface, if you were wondering how I get to save this image.

I saw this answer on StackOverflow : [Which datatype for base64 encoded image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363421/which-datatype-for-base64-encoded-image) but it's for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64-encoded data is just text, so you could use a `Memo` field in Access 2010.